# Python - steady rain

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to create a steady rain in Python pygame and have stumbled upon one issue. When I do not input the part of the code for movement, the grid of raindrops is there without an issue. However, when I add the movement the grid disappears and only one row of moving raindrops is left there. See the code below:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from raindrop import Raindrop
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_width, 
settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("13-3")

    # Make raindrop group.
    raindrops = Group()

    # Create the raindrops.
    gf.create_raindrops(settings, screen, raindrops)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        gf.update_raindrops(raindrops)
        gf.update_screen(settings, screen, raindrops)

        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (0, 0, 255)

        # Raindrop settings
        self.raindrop_speed_factor = 1
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from raindrop import Raindrop

def update_screen(settings, screen, raindrops):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(settings.bg_color)
    raindrops.draw(screen)

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

def get_number_raindrops_x(settings, raindrop_width):
    """Determine the number of raindrops that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = settings.screen_width - 2 * raindrop_width
    number_raindrops_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * raindrop_width))
    return number_raindrops_x

def get_number_rows(settings, raindrop_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of raindrops that fit on the screen."""
    available_space_y = settings.screen_height - (2 * raindrop_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * raindrop_height))
    return number_rows

def create_raindrop(settings, screen, raindrops, raindrop_number, row_number):
    """Create a raindrop and place it in the row."""
    raindrop = Raindrop(settings, screen)
    raindrop_width = raindrop.rect.width
    raindrop.x = raindrop_width + 2 * raindrop_width * raindrop_number
    raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
    raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
    raindrops.add(raindrop)

def create_raindrops(settings, screen, raindrops):
    """Create a full sky of raindrops."""
    # Create a raindrop and find the number of raindrops in a row.
    raindrop = Raindrop(settings, screen)
    number_raindrops_x = get_number_raindrops_x(settings, raindrop.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(settings, raindrop.rect.height)

    # Create the full sky of raindrops.
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for raindrop_number in range(number_raindrops_x):
            create_raindrop(settings, screen, raindrops, raindrop_number, row_number)

def update_raindrops(raindrops):
    """Update the positions of all raindrops in sky."""
    raindrops.update()
```

raindrop.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Raindrop(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single raindrop in the sky."""

    def __init__(self, settings, screen):
        """Initialize the raindrop and set its starting position."""
        super(Raindrop, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings

        # Load the raindrop image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/raindrop.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new raindrop near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        """Move raindrop down."""
        self.y += self.settings.raindrop_speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the raindrop at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I know that the solution for this (from a different thread - thanks to gammazero) is to change this:

```
raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
```

to:

```
raindrop.y = raindrop.rect.height + 2 * raindrop.rect.height * row_number
raindrop.rect.y = raindrop.y
```

I would like to know why and cannot find the answer. Can anyone please explain what the change of code above actually does differently and why it suddenly works?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the raindrop and set its `rect`'s `y` to some position, the actual `raindrop.y` is set to some default value. `Raindrop.update()` uses `Raindrop.y`, not `Raindrop.rect.y` to get the drop's current position. All the replacement code does is assign a proper value to `raindrop.y`, which is then used to set `raindrop.rect.y`